# Flutter RawKeybardListener returns only space before Android 11 devices

Tags: android, flutter, dart, terminal, barcode

We have an offline terminal application that reads barcode from internal barcode reader of the Android device. It clearly works in the Android 11+ terminals like **read barcodes write the textfield and search in the database automatically.** But before Android 11 devices `RawKeybardListener` triggers but only return String with a lot of spaces. When I focus `TextField()` and mobile keyboard opens, it can read and write barcodes like 11+ devices.

Here is my scanning code:

```
RawKeyboardListener(
              focusNode: _textNode,
              autofocus: true,
              onKey: (key){
                if(key.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent' && focus_control)
                {
                  //This operation gets barcode chars and display on TextField()
                  create_doc_single_barcode.text += key.data.keyLabel.toString();
                  if(armada_create_doc_single_barcode.text != "")
                  {
                    //This operation waits 500ms for all chars. If writing is done
                    // it starts searching in the database.
                    _onChangeHandler(create_doc_single_barcode.text);
                  }
                }
              },
```

- I have tried WIFI and USB debugging but cannot find any error in console
- I have connected device via USB and looked Logcat of Application that Release mode but found nothing too.

Have you encountered this situation before? If you have encountered it, what is the solution to the problem?

Additionally, I opened this issue because I thought it was related to the Android Version. Could the problem be caused by another situation?

I would be happy if you help me...

Comment: I had a similar issue with Zebra devices. My solution was to be very careful with the focus node. Request the focus each time you need to scan. It can be done on other types of widgets not necessarily a `TextField()` if you don't want the keyboard